# PostgresSql 9.6 deletes suddenly became slow

Tags: postgresql

I have a database table where debug log entries are recorded. There are no foreign keys - it is a single standalone table.

I wrote a utility to delete a number of entries starting with the oldest.

There are 65 million entries so I deleted them 100,000 at a time to give some progress feedback to the user.

There is a primary key column called id

All was going fine until it got to about 5,000,000 million records remaining. Then it started taking over 1 minute to execute.

What is more, if I used PgAdmin and type the query in myself, but use an Id that I know is less than the minimum id, it still takes over one minute to execute!

I.e: **delete from public.inettklog where id <= 56301001**
And I know the min(id) is 56301002

Here is the result of an explain analyze

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your stats are way out of date. It thinks it will find 30 million rows, but instead finds zero. ANALYZE the table.

Comment: I don't understand. I was running a simple deletion application. All of a sudden it stopped. Now you are telling me the "stats" are out of date? How could they be in date one second and out of date the next? Are you saying the only solution is to continually execute analyze to keep it in sync???? What kind of database is this? And "id" is a primary index. It should know immediately that there are no qualifying rows

Comment: I mean, why is it doing a Seq Scan at all -- "id" is indexed

Comment: @user2577528 Deleting rows modifies the table, so the database's idea of the data distribution is no longer accurate. So the database estimates wrong and thinks that a sequential scan is faster than an index scan, as it sometimes is. Calculating statistics anew fixes the estimates.

Comment: Seems odd that I, as an ignorant user of the database, need to constantly tweak the database. To me the only time a sequential scan would be faster than an index scan would be if the number of rows in the table is small. 30 million is not small. Anyway, what I have done is after every 50 delete operations (i.e. 5 million rows) I run ANALYZE