# Inexplicable query times for small PostgreSql database

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple table that we use to record debug logs.

There are only 1000 rows in the table.

There are a handful of columns - id (primary), date (indexed), level, a few other small fields and message which could be a large string.

if I query:

```
select id from public.log
```

### the query completes very quickly (less than 1 second)
[image]

if I query:

```
select id,date from public.log
```

or

```
select * from public.log
```

it takes **1 minute and 28 seconds** to complete!

90 Seconds to read 1000 records from a database!
[image]

however if I query:

```
select * 
from public.log 
where id in (select id from public.log)
```

it completes in about 1 second.
[image]

And here is the CREATE - I just had pgAdmin generate them for me

```
-- Table: public.inettklog

-- DROP TABLE public.inettklog;

CREATE TABLE public.inettklog
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('inettklog_id_seq'::regclass),
    date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    thread character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    level character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    logger character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    customlevel integer,
    source character varying(64) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    logentry json,
    CONSTRAINT inettklog_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.inettklog
    OWNER to postgres;

-- Index: inettklog_ix_logdate

-- DROP INDEX public.inettklog_ix_logdate;

CREATE INDEX inettklog_ix_logdate
    ON public.inettklog USING btree
    (date)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) for the slow query generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your table is extremely bloated.  Given your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62925137/postgressql-9-6-deletes-suddenly-became-slow), this extreme bloat is not surprising.

You can fix this with a VACUUM FULL.

Going forward, you should avoid getting into this situation in the first place, by deleting records as they become obsolete rather than waiting until 99.998% of them are obsolete before acting.

Comment: Background: A system was given to the customer. The logs are culled to be no more than 30 days old. The customer did something (perfectly legal, but unusual) that generated a bazillion log entries in a short period of time. The C drive filled up with the database. We cannot do a VACUUM FULL because it needs disk space!

Comment: The amount of disk space taken by VACUUM FULL depends on the "live" tuples left in the table, not the original very bloated size of the table.  So with 1000 rows it should need very little additional disk space.  If you can't scrounge up even that amount, maybe drop the index and re-create it later.